# Incorrect new answers notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, grammar, plurals

Is Gollum working for Stack Overflow?

[image: 1 new answers]

(Although I guess it would be "answerses" if he was.)

Comment: Are you a software developer?  If you are, you already know why this happens.  See also https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ouch. Although I would welcome Jeff (even if he was carrying a big S) for taking the long trip to Germany :) (Of course I know why this happens, which is why I assiduously avoid it in my code)

Comment: Given that this almost always shows 1 new answer(s) and very rarely several new answers this one seems more fix worthy than the others

Comment: I don't understand why these types of errors come up all the time. I never have them when I write code. `"answer"+(has_multiple_whatzits ? "s" : "")+"to this question"`

Comment: Or even simpler; user answer(s) rather than answers

Comment: @Emrakul `"answersto this question"`? :P

Comment: @Doorknob Fair enough. Now I see why it is so difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed (probably a long time ago), it now says "1 new answer to this question".

[image: notification saying "1 new answer to this question"]

Comment: Gollum has been taught proper grammar.  He hates it foreverrrr....